# RESTful web applications using WAN IP instead of localhost

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, networking, ip

I am developing a web application in Java by using RESTful web services and Tomcat. So far I was using the localhost in the URI: `http://localhost:8080/3.ServerAPI/rest/Variable`. But what if I want to use the real IP?

I have tried that on a local network by replacing the localhost with the LAN IP and it works fine: `http://192.168.1.2:8080/3.ServerAPI/rest/Variable`
The application at this address received the Variable.

If I want to send this through the internet as long as I know I have to use the WAN IP: `http://188.39.25.247:8080/3.ServerAPI/rest/Variable`

My question is, if I use the last URI with the WAN IP do I need also to port forward to the LAN IP by configuring the router or it is going to work like when I used the LAN IP ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: It should work directly as it is provided you are connected to internet.

Comment: I'm not sure this really fits on this site. The simple answer is that your WAN IP is for your router/modem. As such, you would have to either run the server on the router/modem or port forward to a machine on your local network. This is purely a network configuration thing, not really programming at all.

Comment: @Satish not very helpful, who these days is connecting directly and not through a router?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your network setup really.

You may have to enable port forwarding on your router to direct the request to the machine that your server is on, also make sure that the router allows connections to port 8080.

I had to do this recently when working with callbacks on external APIs. Seem to remember that I had to enable port forwarding on my router to get it to work. Wasn't too difficult though, just check router instructions on how to do it - like I say, depends on network setup though.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have developed in the past a similar application with TCP/IP and I used there port forwarding to make it work. But what if I have one application on the server that sends messages to another application that is used by many remote users ?? All these users must access their router and do a port forwarding ??

Comment: @user3358377 I think you need to rethink this from the start. Keep in mind, when you look at things on the Internet, the individual networks connected together each appear as just one machine, you don't really see that behind one global IP is many machines on a network.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something similar to this and the problem was due to the port being used by another application.

Comment: it is the cause, please describe the solution

Comment: In the URL when I use machine name or IP address it worked fine the moment I use localhost I got 404 error. Which means it can contact server but not execute the request but my breakpoint never hit. Then it seems to be some other application running on that port. When I changed the port it all worked fine. In your case did you try changing the port? did it solve your problem are getting the same issue?